# PHP session is dying on refresh why?

Tags: php, session

Hi each time im refreshing or click a button that reload  my index page ... which is my main page, the session dies .... here is a simple of code :

```
//session.class.php
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["EMAIL"] = "";

$_SESSION["LOGED"]  = 0;

?>

//index.php
<?php
include_once ('session.class.php');
if (isset($_GET['login'])) {/// it a button submit in my form that use for login
    $_SESSION["LOGED"] = 1;
    include ("/module/Users/profile.php");// class that show profile if login an 
                                          // password is good
    echo  "session = ".$_SESSION["LOGED"];
}
if ($_SESSION["LOGED"] == 0) {
    echo userFormLogin();//show login 
    echo "<a href=index.php?content=register>Register</a>";
}

?>
```

TY every one :D

Comment: What does *"the session dies"* actually mean? Could it be that when you `include` the `session.class.php` file, it clears the `EMAIL` property and sets `LOGED` to zero?

Comment: it mean when the page refresh .... my session variable is reset to 0 ..... so it not seeing that im stil log as an user

Comment: hummm i guess it possible but i dont know the way arround .... if it the prob i have no idia to how setting the session variable to zero only one time and not overwrite it ...

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['LOGED']) || $_SESSION['LOGED'] = 0;`

Comment: can you post: session.class.php to pastebin.com

Answer (score 1):

Every time you load page, your EMAIL and LOGED session variables get reset. You don't need to declare them, SESSIONS don't exist until you make one. You are basically creating session but when you load page it gets set to 0 and you ask for login again.

You should use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['LOGED'])){
actions for logged in
}
else{
show login page
}
```